# Windows phone ads don't show up

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I put my adcontrol control to my page. While using test unitid and test appid the ads show up. When I type my app ID and normal adunitid anything shows up in emulator. Place where ad should be visible is transparent.

one more q; how can I "pin" my ad to scroll at the bottom of the screen with scrollviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I type my app ID and normal adunitid anything shows up in emulator

Many ad-providers are able to detect the emulator and turn off the ads. Deploy to a real device to test them.

> how can I "pin" my ad to scroll at the bottom of the screen with scrollviewer?

Just change the layout of your page and put the adcontrol outside of the scrollviewer. For instance:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Whatever -->
    </ScrollViewer>

    <AdControl Grid.Row="1" AdUnit="..." />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The only problem is that I don't have any device. (maybe it sounds stupid, that I develop apps without phone) but thank you anyway!

Comment: it doesn't sound stupid not to have any device. but having a device make development slightly easily. some choose to get a device at a later stage of the development process.

Answer (score 0):

- To find out what is the problem with the Ad control, register to the `AdControlError` event and look at the `e.ErrorCode` and `e.ErrorDescription`.
- I don't think that "pinning" the ad control at the bottom of a ScrollViewer is a good idea. You'd better place both the `ScrollViewer` and the `AdControl` inside a `Grid` with two rows.